# Существует ли ФГИС ЕГРН API?

Tags: поиск-api, росреестр

Существует ли API-сервис для получения данных из ФГИС ЕГРН или какой-либо иной способ получения выписок ЕГРН из Росреестра?

Answer (score 16):

Описание веб-сервисов: http://pkk5.rosreestr.ru/help/pkk5_services.docx

Веб-сервисы: http://pkk5.rosreestr.ru/arcgis/rest/services

Открытые данные: https://rosreestr.ru/wps/portal/cc_ib_opendata

Описание «сервиса Росреестра прямого доступа»: http://rosreestr.ru/wps/portal/cc_ib_documents?documentId=1521

> Веб-сервис прямого взаимодействия обеспечивает полный цикл оказания
>   государственных услуг Росреестра в электронном виде (от подачи запроса
>   и информирования заявителя о ходе исполнения услуги до предоставления
>   результата оказания услуги в виде электронного документа).
>
> Предоставление сведений государственного кадастра недвижимости о
>   земельном участке в виде кадастрового паспорта объекта недвижимости;
>
> Предоставление сведений государственного кадастра недвижимости о
>   земельном участке в виде кадастровой выписки;
>
> Предоставление сведений государственного кадастра недвижимости о
>   территории в пределах кадастрового квартала в виде кадастрового плана
>   территории;
>
> Постановка на государственный кадастровый учет земельного участка;
>
> Постановка на государственный кадастровый учет объекта капитального
>   строительства.
>
> Предоставление выписки из ЕГРП о правах отдельного лица;
>
> Предоставление выписки из ЕГРП о зарегистрированных правах на объект
>   недвижимого имущества (земельные участки и объекты капитального
>   строительства).

---

Ещё есть **описание REST-ресурсов сервиса «Онлайн-Справка» версии 0.0.2**

**Макро-регионы**

```
http://rosreestr.ru/api/online/macro_regions
```

---

**Типы дочерних регионов**

```
http://rosreestr.ru/api/online/region_types/{parent-id}
```

Пример: `http://rosreestr.ru/api/online/region_types/104201000000`

---

**Дочерние регионы по идентификатору родителя**

```
http://rosreestr.ru/api/online/regions/{parent-id}
```

Пример: `http://rosreestr.ru/api/online/regions/104201000000`

---

**Поиск объекта по идентификатору**

```
http://rosreestr.ru/api/online/fir_object/{object-id}
```

Пример: `http://rosreestr.ru/api/online/fir_object/2:56:30302:639`

---

**Поиск объектов по номеру**

```
http://rosreestr.ru/api/online/fir_objects/{number}
```

Пример: `http://rosreestr.ru/api/online/fir_objects/2:56:30302:639`

Результат: 0 или множество (не больше 200) объектов, удовлетворяющих маске номера.

---

**Поиск объекта по коду региона и номеру права или ограничения**

```
http://rosreestr.ru/api/right/{region}/{number}
```

Пример: `http://rosreestr.ru/api/online/right/177/50-50-21%2F042%2F2012-234`

Результат: 0 или 1 объект, номер права или ограничения которого совпал с указанным номером.

---

**Поиск объектов методом GET**

```
http://rosreestr.ru/api/online/address/fir_objects?macroRegionId=140000000000&RegionId=140281000000&street=Полевая&house=1
```

Передаваемые поля. Числа в виде строк:

- `macroRegionId` — id макрорегиона
- `regionId` — id региона
- `settlementId` — id населенного пункта

Передаваемые поля. Строки:

- `settlementType` — тип населенного пункта (необязательное поле, фильтрует населенные пункты от типа)
- `street` — наименование улицы
- `house` — номер дома
- `apartment` — номер квартиры
- `building` — номер корпуса
- `structure` — номер строения
- `streetType` — тип улицы (необятельное поле)

Возможные значения streetType:

```
str1=Улица
str2=Переулок
str3=Проспект
str4=Площадь
str5=Микрорайон
str6=Аллея
str7=Бульвар
str8=Аал
str9=Аул
str10=Въезд
str11=Выселки
str12=Городок
str13=Деревня
str14=Дорога
str15=ж/д остановочный (обгонный) пункт
str16=Железнодорожная будка
str17=Железнодорожная казарма
str18=Железнодорожная платформа
str19=Железнодорожная станция
str20=Железнодорожный пост
str21=Железнодорожный разъезд
str22=Животноводческая точка
str23=Заезд
str24=Казарма
str25=Квартал
str26=Километр
str27=Кольцо
str28=Линия
str29=Местечко
str30=Набережная
str31=Населенный пункт
str32=Остров
str33=Парк
str34=Переезд
str35=Планировочный район
str36=Платформа
str37=Площадка
str38=Полустанок
str39=Поселок/станция
str40=Поселок сельского типа
str41=Починок
str42=Почтовое отделение
str43=Проезд
str44=Просек
str45=Проселок
str46=Проулок
str47=Разъезд
str48=Сад
str49=Село
str50=Сквер
str51=Слобода
str52=Станция
str53=Строение
str54=Территория
str55=Тракт
str56=Тупик
str57=Участок
str58=Хутор
str59=Шоссе
```

Comment: Python библиотека для работы с «Онлайн-Справка» API и pkk5 API - https://github.com/GregEremeev/rosreestr-api

Comment: @Greg Eremeev, Ваше приложение pkk5 API у меня не работает

Comment: @РамзесЖданов Напишите issue на github

Answer (score 8):

Если я не ошибаюсь, то вот [API версия 3.0 Beta
для работы с Росреестром в режиме on-line](https://apirosreestr.ru/)

Авторизация и методы написаны, соответственно, [на этой странице](https://apirosreestr.ru/api/)

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, это не официальное API.

Comment: @DanilPyatnitsev да, но совсем совсем официального нет

Comment: Если совсем совсем официального нет, откуда берут данные эти сервисы?

Answer (score 5):

Поиск объектов по адресу - не методом POST, а методом GET. В документации автором допущена ошибка. Рабочий пример запроса к API:

[http://rosreestr.ru/api/online/address/fir_objects?macroRegionId=140000000000&RegionId=140281000000&street=Полевая&house=1](http://rosreestr.ru/api/online/address/fir_objects?macroRegionId=140000000000&RegionId=140281000000&street=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F&house=1)

Кому, вдруг, пригодится: https://github.com/KirillNaumkin/RosreestrREST - NET-либа для встраивания в свои приложения функционала запроса к сервисам РР и мини-приложение для тестирования либы. Там же подробно расписана структура ответов сервиса.

Answer (score 1):

Сервис Каднет предоставляет API v2 для отправки запросов в Росреестр ФГИС ЕГРН https://api.kadnet.ru/

Документация методов https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/2625849/kadnet-api/6tgTfhm#intro

.Net Client https://github.com/kadnet/kadnet.apiv2.dotnet